# How to set timezone in date field using jodatime library

Tags: datetime, java-7, jodatime

I am using JodaTime2 library to create a date object with a given timezone as follow:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
System.out.println("timezone=" + tz);
Date d = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, tz).toDate();
System.out.println("Cur Date = " + d);
```

However when I print this date, the timezone reported is CST. What am I missing ?

```
timezone=America/New_York
Cur Date = Tue Jan 01 13:00:00 CST 2013
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing out the value of a `Date` object. `Date` doesn't *have* a time zone - `Date.toString()` always just uses the "default" time zone. A `Date` is *just* a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch; it doesn't know about calendars or time zones.

You should either just stick within the Joda Time world, or (if you must) use a `SimpleDateFormatter` to convert a `Date` to a `String` - you can set the time zone on the formatter.